# Accidently removed all PHP dynamic libraries

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php5, php.ini, startup

I was trying to remove a startup module folder(ioncube) and accidently removed the PHP startup modules/extensions folder (debian)

Now I'm getting this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mcrypt.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mcrypt.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pdo_pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pgsql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/pgsql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/suhosin.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I was unable to find any doc related to re-installing those.. I tried re-installing PHP but doesn't seem to work

Is there anyway I could recover those files back.

EDIT: I don't know the reason for downvoting this but i got no backup.

Comment: 1. Is there a reason you're not restoring from backup? 2. What OS/Distro is this?

Comment: No backups available, it is Debian using apache2.

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because SF is about professional server management. Having no backups is not professional.

Comment: I do whatever feels right for my server and myself. Having no backups because I am "professionally" aware of commands I use; I hope you understood when I said "accidently deleted with different files".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the extensions are not provided by PHP5 package. here is the list for Debian Squeeze

https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/php/

Pick those extensions by their proper name then reinstall with apt-get

Eg: `apt-get reinstall php5-mysql`

some of them can only be installed by PECL http://pecl.php.net/

Eg: `pecl install pdo`